# Finding the number of correct animals from a file using php

Tags: javascript, php

English teacher teaches animals names to the kids. To make the children to learn with interest, she would like to teach animals names through a game. Animal’s names to be displayed from the “animals.txt” file in the web page in single click event and disappeared in double click event of the animal button. Now the child has to type the names of animals (what she/he knows) as a sentence (animals names are words of the sentence) in a text type input. Also it should display that how many animals’ names have been typed correctly according to the “animals.txt” file in the click event of display button. Order of the animal’s names in text file and input sentence is immaterial.  Develop the minimal online application for this scenario.
Make sure that 
 (i) Text input field should be present to the child only after the click event of input button.
(ii) Display and input buttons should be deactivated till the user pop up the data from the text file “animals.txt”.

so i created a animals.txt file stored a few animals names and wrote the script as follows

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("animals.txt");
?>

<script>
function animals(){
    document.getElementById("animals").style["visibility"] = "visible";
    document.getElementById("view_button").style["visibility"] = "visible";
}

function showInput(){
    document.getElementById("text").style["visibility"] = "visible";
    document.getElementById("answer_button").style["visibility"] = "visible";
}
function hideAnimals(){
    document.getElementById("animals").style["visibility"] = "hidden";
}
function checkInput(){
    var file_input = document.getElementById("animals").innerHTML;
    file_input = file_input.substr(1);
    var input = document.getElementById("text").value;

    file_input = file_input.split(" ");
    input = input.split(" ");

    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < file_input.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < input.length; j++)
        {
            if(file_input[i] == input[j])
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = count+" animals answered correctly";
}


</script>

<div id="animals" style="visibility:hidden">
<?php echo $text ?>
</div>

<button onclick="animals()" ondblclick="hideAnimals()">Animals</button>

<br>
<button id = "view_button" onclick="showInput()" style="visibility:hidden">Input</button> <br><br>
<input id = "text" style="visibility:hidden" placeholder="Type a line"></input>  <br><br>
<button id = "answer_button" onclick="checkInput()" style="visibility:hidden">Display</button> <br><br>

<div id="result"></div> <br><br>
```

but when i enter even non listed animal names, it gives me 0 wrong answer and i cant figure out the problem here

Comment: Just add `console.log(file_input[i], input[j]);` above the compare string `if(file_input[i] == input[j])` and you'll get the answer.

Comment: I cannot fined wherever you search for the wrong answer - as far as I can see you only count the correct answers. I also recommend to use in_array instead of your double loop